# How to turn off phone carrier HTML optimizations?

Tags: html, networking, mobile

I made an app which provides a schedule for the pupils at my school. It gets its data from the school's online schedule service. Due to the lack for a real API, I reverse-engineerd the website: Now, the app parses it with string operations basically.

And here's the problem: The string searches do not match on certain mobile carriers' networks because **they're stripping away the spaces** and other foo. Is there an universal way to turn that off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is up to the carrier and even if there was a way to disable it, it would be non-standard and not worth addressing.

Additionally, you should not use string operations but a real HTML parser, like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) is for Java (there is a .NET port too, [NSoup](https://nsoup.codeplex.com/)). If you look at the examples, it is relatively easy to use and will protect your application from space normalizations and any other change in the markup irrelevant to your application.

For data stored in inline JavaScript, you could first extract the right node from the document and then use a regex to trim the relevant parts. Or you could also use a regex on the HTML document as a whole, but remember that you *can't really parse HTML using regexes*.

Adopting another strategy, request pages over HTTPs rather than HTTP (if the server supports TLS/SSL) so that they can't be manipulated by the carrier.

Comment: Yeah, I already considered that but, for example, the list of groups is stored in inline JavaScript and not in HTML. In addition, I'm using Xamarin Starter for porting to Android and iOS which doesn't allow third party libs. I could use XDocument from .NET but the site isn't XML compliant. Do you have any ideas how to archive the thing anyway?

Comment: See the edit. And, I don't know about your country, but in mine websites for public institutions like schools are required by the Law to be usable also with JavaScript disabled, so that screenreaders for blind pupils and/or parents actually read something fully understandable. See if it applies to you and report it as appropriate.

Comment: Well, these things are *bad* in Germany - the site uses frames and everything. But thanks for responding!!

Comment: I strongly doubt it, but if the website accepts SSL/TLS connections, then you could access the pages via HTTPs so that they can't be manipulated by the carrier.

Comment: It's like they want to make fun of tech-savy people: The error message is `www.cws-usingen.de uses an invalid certificate. The certificate only applies to *.your-server.de. (Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)`
They didn't even disable HTTPS.

Comment: See if you can ignore the certificate validation and just establish an encrypted connection. While this is **BAD** for the real purpose of SSL (privacy and authenticity), here you just want the carrier not to manipulate your markup.